# Preserve white space and new lines in xdocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xmldocument

i have xml file which looks something like this,

Question) how do I preserve all the white space and new line breaks while loading the document, when I load it through XDcoument.
LoadOptions.PreseveWhitesapce does not  work

Thanks.

```
 <!--
********************************************************
 header
********************************************************
    -->
   <!--sample -->
   <realmCode
      code="US"/>
   
   <!-- sample -->
   <typeId
      root="2.16.840.1.113883.1.3"
      extension="samo"/>
   
   <!-- sample -->
   <!-- sample -->
   <templateId
      root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.1.1"/>
   <!-- *** formatting. *** -->
   <!-- formatting -->
   <templateId
      root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.1.2"/>
   
   <!-- formatting -->
   <id`
      extension="samo"
      root="1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1"/>
   
   <!--formatting -->"
```

Comment: "does not work" is not enough to figure out what exactly is happening - please review [MCVE] guidance on posting code for debugging questions and edit accordingly.

Comment: Please give more details about the problem that are you face it. What do you mean with "does not work"? Do you have an specific error about it?

Comment: Thank you for your response, and yes my sample is not complete but just to give an idea about the issue I am facing.  My problem is that I need to preserve white space and new line breaks, as I need to capture the exact line numbers of the original file.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML example have few troubles, which should be "fixed" before parsing XML:

1. Missing root element. It could be added manually before parsing your example.
2. Invalid grave accent character (**`**, at "<id` extension..."). Should be removed.
3. Trailing double quote without purpose.
4. Line breaks (doesn't affects on parse, but should be fixed too). Whitespaces isn't trouble at all.

So, to fix them all, first you should read XML file as simple single string with `System.IO.File.ReadAllText`. Then you can use `Regex` class from `System.Text.RegularExpressions` namespace and its method `Replace()` with pattern " **@"[`\r\n]"** " to remove line breaks and invalid grave accent `char at. Double quote at the end of document could be simply trimmed with`Trim` method.

As your XML example haven't root element, what would cause `System.Xml.XmlException` with `Missing root element` message when you will try to `Parse` it, we add it manually with concatenation of some root tag: `"<root>" + fixedXmlString + "</root>"`.

Whole piece of code looks like that:

```
static void Main()
{
    // Reading XML file as string.
    // Replacing invalid grave accent ` 
    // Replacing line breaks
    // Trimming trailing double quote
    var xmlString = Regex.Replace(File.ReadAllText("example.xml"), @"[`\r\n]", "").Trim('\"');

    // Adding some root element as it doesn't exists in example
    xmlString = "<root>" + xmlString + "</root>";

    // Now it parsable
    XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);

    // Save as correct one
    xDoc.Save("example_fixed.xml");
}
```

Output (after `.Save()`) looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response, and yes my sample is not complete but just to give an idea about the issue I am facing.  My problem is I need to preserve white space and new line breaks, as I need to capture the exact line numbers of the original file.

Comment: "Exact line number of original file"? You mean parse XML like regular text? Really sure that is good approach?

Comment: we have a specific business case, where we need to show the line number of an uploaded file.